# background color css IE 8 issue

Tags: css

As expected this code doesn't work in IE 8

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

Is there any fix for IE.Please let me know.

Many thanks,
R

Comment: can you not just user background-color: #000; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a fallback background-color property like so:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

or

```
background-color: #fff;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
*background-color: #FFF;
```

Also, you are using opacity 1, do you really need to use rgba here?

Some help:
http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

Comment: Thanks actually I have to use rgba here in my case.I could use opacity 1 but could not.

Comment: Ok then keep in mind that the fallback *background-color will not have opacity, you may have to adjust the color of the fallback or alternatively use filter css attribute to obtain similar behavior for IE7/IE8

Answer (score 0):

For IE, if you want equivalent of background-color:rgba(....)
use this :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);
```

This is black color with opacity (the two first digits)

Here one generator for that: 
http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/

Comment: Thanks mate.I have used Stefan's suggestion.But I will definitely test yours later tonight.